# How do I create an outlook rule to resend an email to a contact group by bcc?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

How do I create an outlook rule to resend an email to a contact group by bcc?

On a particular email account whenever I receive an email I would like to resend this email to a group of people, and I'd only like their email addresses to be in the bcc field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the rule to "run a script". **Now tested code**.

```
Sub ForwardBcc(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

    Dim myRecip as Outlook.Recipient
    Dim myForward As mailitem

    Set myForward = Item.Forward
    Set myRecip = myForward.Recipients.Add("Dist List Name")

    myRecip.Resolve
    myRecip.Type = olBCC 

    myForward.Display ' Remove when tested
    ' myForward.Send  ' Uncomment when ready

End Sub


Sub ForwardBcc_Test
    ' Open a message
    Dim item as mailitem
    Set item = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    ForwardBcc item
End Sub
```